# Flutter: Widgets in Row are not aligned

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I use row widget with two widgets inside, a text widget and iconbutton but iconbutton is not aligned with text and I don't know how to do it. This is a screenshot to show you

[image]

```
Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
        child: widgets[index],
      ),
      IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.close,
            size: 25,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
          onPressed: () => {
                setState(() {
                  widgets.remove(widgets[index]);
                }),
              })
    ],
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used InkWell instead of iconbutton and it works

Answer (score 1):

Use `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,`

```
Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  child: Text(
                    'Theo',
                    style:
                        TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent, fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.close,
                      size: 25,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => {})
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: I hope it helped you, Could you please accept the answer so others can refer it.

Answer (score 0):

replace `CrossAxisAlignment.start` with `CrossAxisAlignment.baseline` and add `textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic` like this:

```
                Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                        child: widgets[index],
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.close,
                            size: 25,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () => {
                                setState(() {
                                  widgets.remove(widgets[index]);
                                }),
                              })
                    ],
                  ),
```

You may need this to confirm:
[image]